# How to sort an Array based on another Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

if I have an array: `[1,2,3,4]` and another array of objects:

```
[{id:2, name:"Alexa"}, {id:1, name:"John"},{id:5 , name:"Mary"},{id:4, name:"Peter"} ],
```

how can I make an optimal function to sort based on the first array?
result:

```
[{id:1, name:"John"},{id:2, name:"Alexa"},{id:4, name:"Peter"},{id:5, name:"Mary"} ]
```

I thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
const initialArr = [
  { id: 2, name: "Alexa" },
  { id: 1, name: "John" },
  { id: 5, name: "Mary" },
  { id: 9, name: "Zuzu" },
  { id: 3, name: "Mary" },
  { id: 4, name: "Peter" }
];
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

initialArr.sort((a, b) => {
  const getTypeIndex = (x) => arr.indexOf(x.id);

  return getTypeIndex(a) - getTypeIndex(b) && a.id - b.id;
});

console.log(initialArr);
```

Comment: it works for me when it is : return getTypeIndex(a) - getTypeIndex(b) || a.id - b.id;